# Given several pairs of dates, how to count number of days in between but don't count overlapping days?

Tags: java, string, date

This question was asked in my interview.

```
String d1="7 dec 2012";
String d2="15 dec 2012";

String d3="12 dec 2012";
String d4="16 dec 2012";

String d5="16 dec 2012";
String d6="24 dec 2012";

Number of days between d1 and d2 is: 9  
Number of days between d3 and d4 is: 1 (12 Dec to 15 Dec counted in d1 and d2,
                                        don't count overlapping days)  
Number of days between d3 and d4 is: 8 (16 Dec counted in d3 and d4, 
                                        don't count overlapping days)

Now final output should be: 9 + 1 + 8
```

What algorithm should I use?

Comment: Seems that you know what to do...

Comment: You can use Calendar in a loop or JodaTime. Now that you've stated the problem, you might like to ask an actual question

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is basic coding(**Very simple basic approach)** to calculate the date difference between 2 days. It does not take into account the daylight savings and any overlapping dates.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TestJava {
 public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2)
 {
     /*This function returns the difference in days given 2 dates as input*/
         return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
 {
     Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
     Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
     Date date = sdf.parse("07122012");  // Date1
     cal1.setTime(date);
     date = sdf.parse("15122012"); // Date2
     cal2.setTime(date);
     int daysBetween = daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime());  // Days between Date1 and Date2
     int interval = daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime());
     System.out.println("Interval1 == "+ interval);

     date = sdf.parse("12122012"); // Date3
     cal1.setTime(date);
     date = sdf.parse("16122012"); // Date4
     cal2.setTime(date);
     daysBetween += daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime()); // Days between Date3 and Date4 is added to the previously available value of days between Date1 and Date2
     interval = daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime());
     System.out.println("Interval2 == "+ interval);

     date = sdf.parse("16122012");
     cal1.setTime(date);
     date = sdf.parse("24122012");
     cal2.setTime(date);
     daysBetween += daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime()); // Total required difference as per the question
     interval = daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime());
     System.out.println("Interval3 == "+ interval);

     System.out.println("Total Interval == "+ daysBetween);
 }
}
```

Comment: This code has an "out by one" error if you `d2` occurs during daylight savings time and `d1` does not.  It's usually wrong to convert milliseconds to days by dividing by `(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` because there are 23-hour days and 25-hour days.

Comment: @DavidWallace:  I just provided a simple approach as answer that could be acceptable in an interview. Ofcourse, for a perfect answer, we need to consider daylight savings and timezones/locales also.

Comment: You don't need to consider timezones and locales.  You only need to worry about the case where `d2` has daylight savings and `d1` doesn't.  The interviewer probably wanted to know whether the interviewee would know this.  Giving an incorrect answer to such a question is not the best way to secure a job.

Comment: I forgot a semi-colon. Check now.

Comment: Also, why are you bothering with the `Calendar` class at all, given that you're only using `Date` for the arithmetic?  This is _much_ more complicated than it should be.

Comment: I had misunderstood the question. I did not take the overlapping scenario into account. My code only calculates the date difference.

Comment: plz solve my problem. ur solution is counting total days between given dates..desired output is : don't count overlapping days... @Nisha

Answer (score 0):

**The problem should be solved in three steps:**

step 1: Find the number of overlapping days.

step 2: Find the difference between the dates given.

step 3: Subtract the difference obtained in step 2 by the number of overlapping days obtained in step 1, which will give u the exact difference between the dates with out overlapping dates counted.........!

**The Code below will serve your purpose:**

```
package mypack;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatesNoOverlap 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String d[]=new String[6];
    d[0]="7/12/2012";
    d[1]="15/12/2012";

    d[2]="12/12/2012";
    d[3]="16/12/2012";

    d[4]="16/12/2012";
    d[5]="24/12/2012";

    int num[]=new int[6];
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<d[i].length();j++)
        {
            if(d[i].charAt(j)=='/')
            {
                num[counter]=Integer.parseInt(d[i].substring(0,j));
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    int sum1=0;
    for(int m=0;m<counter-1;m++)
    {
        if(m>0&&m%2!=0)
        {
            if(num[m+1]<=num[m])
            {
                sum1=sum1+(num[m]-num[m+1]+1);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Number of overlapping days........="+sum1);
    long sum2=0;
    for(int n=0;n<counter-1;n=n+2)
    {       
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(d[n]);
        d2 = format.parse(d[n+1]);
        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    sum2=sum2+diffDays+1;
    }
            catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Complete Difference = "+sum2);
    System.out.println("Exact Difference = "+(sum2-sum1));
}

}
```

Comment: Like the other answer that's currently here, this gets it wrong 25% of the time, for the same reason.  Do not think you can convert milliseconds to days by dividing by `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.